# When I change interactive sequences on the slide timeline in powerpoint during a slide show, the changes don't take effect until a slideshow restart

Tags: vba, animation, sequence, timeline, powerpoint-2010

I'm new here, so please forgive any transgressions. I am writing some code which will copy a picture shape on a slide, move the copy to a new place on the slide and add some animations to the new picture which are triggered interactively by clicking on a shape. The code works great outside of slideshow mode, and it technically works inside slideshow mode too, but only after I restart the slideshow.

This is my problem. I want the animations to update and trigger inside the slideshow. Updating animations on the MainSequence timeline works just fine, but the interactive sequences timeline doesn't update inside the slideshow.  Is there a workaround for this? Or is this just a "feature" of powerpoint?

Thanks.
Code:

```
Sub CopyPicAddAnimation()
    Dim sourcePic As Shape
    Dim targetPic As Shape
    Dim btnShp As Shape
    Dim frame As Shape
    Dim targetSlide As Integer
    Dim sourceSlide As Integer
    Dim pastedShapes As ShapeRange
    
    
    Dim seqInteractive As Sequence
    
    Dim effSwivelAppear As Effect
    Dim effSwivelDisapper As Effect
    Dim effAppear As Effect
    Dim effDisappear As Effect
    
    targetSlide = 2
    sourceSlide = 2
    
    Set sourcePic = ActivePresentation.Slides(sourceSlide).Shapes("img1")
    Set frame = ActivePresentation.Slides(targetSlide).Shapes("frame1")
    Set btnShp = ActivePresentation.Slides(targetSlide).Shapes("btn1")
    
    sourcePic.Copy
    
    Set pastedShapes = ActivePresentation.Slides(targetSlide).Shapes.Paste
    
    Set targetPic = pastedShapes(1)
    
    targetPic.Name = "NewPic"
    targetPic.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    targetPic.Width = frame.Width
    targetPic.Height = frame.Height
    targetPic.Top = frame.Top
    targetPic.Left = frame.Left
    
    Set seqInteractive = ActivePresentation.Slides(targetSlide).TimeLine. _
      InteractiveSequences.Add()
      
    Set effSwivelAppear = seqInteractive.AddEffect(Shape:=targetPic, _
      effectId:=msoAnimEffectSwivel, trigger:=msoAnimTriggerOnShapeClick)

    With effSwivelAppear.Timing
        .Duration = 1.5
        .TriggerShape = btnShp
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Oh, Some workarounds I have already tried include advancing and returning to the slide in the slideshow manually, and having the slideshow redirect itself to the slide with new animations again using VBA code. Moving around the slideshow doesn't seem to help the animations on the slide refresh.

The button shape that I designated for the shape to trigger the animation remains completely un-clickable in the slideshow.

It is frustrating that the MainTimeline can update in the slideshow just fine, but the interactive timeline seems to no update at all until the slideshow is exited and started up again.